# Errors when setting up Shell Launcher Extension for VSCode with Anaconda Prompt and Git Bash

Tags: json, shell, cmd, visual-studio-code, anaconda

I'm having trouble getting anaconda prompt to work with VSCode shell launcher.

Im trying to set up  the Shell Launcher Extension for VSCode to run the following terminals on windows 10: 
Git Bash,
CMD,
Powershell, 
Anaconda Prompt

I have configured my settings. json with the following code:

```
 {  
  "terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "C:\\Program Files\\Git\\bin\\bash.exe",
  "shellLauncher.shells.windows": [
    {
      "shell": "C:\\Program Files\\Git\\bin\\bash.exe",
      "args": [],
      "label": "bash"
    },
    {
      "shell": "cmd",
      "args": [],
      "label": "cmd"
    },
    {
      "shell": "C:\\Windows\\System32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe",
      "args": [],
      "label": "PowerShell"
    },
    {
      "shell": "cmd",
      "args": [
        "/K",
        "C:\\ProgramData\\Anaconda3\\Scripts\\activate.bat C:\\ProgramData\\Anaconda3"
      ],
      "label": "Conda"
    }
  ]
}
```

As you can see Bash is my default terminal that opens with **ctrl+`** and my shell launcher opens with **ctrl+shift+t** .

The Shell launcher lists my all of the entries above, and all terminals launch through Shell Launcher except Anaconda Prompt.

From what I understand according to this blog post: [How to Add Anaconda Prompt to VSCode Integrated Terminal](https://mscodingblog.blogspot.com/2017/08/setup-integrated-terminal-in-vs-code-to.html),
Anaconda Prompt extends windows cmd and I just need to pass in the Arguments that run the script.

I pulled the args out of the properties of Anaconda menu, but when I try to launch the anaconda prompt I get the following error message:

**The terminal process command 'cmd /K 'C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Scripts\activate.bat C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3'' failed to launch (exit code: 2)**

Here is the path from the properties menu of the anaconda prompt desktop icon that works normally.

```
%windir%\System32\cmd.exe "/K" C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Scripts\activate.bat C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3
```

I have tried adding the actual path of cmd as:

```
%windir%\\System32\\cmd.exe
```

, but this just removes the Anaconda prompt from the Shell Launcher drop-down menu completely.

How can I fix this?

Any help will be appreciated. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it.  "cmd.exe" was the path that worked.

For anyone else who want's to set up multiple integrated terminals in VScode for windows 10 here's the settings for the Shell Launcher extension that I am using.

This sets the my default terminal to Git Bash and allows me to open bash, cmd, Anaconda prompt and powershell with Shell Launcher.

```
  "terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "C:\\Program Files\\Git\\bin\\bash.exe",
  "shellLauncher.shells.windows": [
    {
      "shell": "C:\\Program Files\\Git\\bin\\bash.exe",
      "args": [],
      "label": "bash"
    },
    {
      "shell": "cmd.exe",
      "args": [],
      "label": "cmd"
    },
    {
      "shell": "cmd.exe",
      "args": [
        "/K",
        "C:\\ProgramData\\Anaconda3\\Scripts\\activate C:\\ProgramData\\Anaconda3"
      ],
      "label": "Conda"
    },
    {
      "shell": "C:\\Windows\\System32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe",
      "args": [],
      "label": "PowerShell"
    }
  ]
```

Happy Hacking. ;)